# Generate JSON from bean method return value with camel routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a bean with a method that construct a list of objects. I want to generate a json with jackson from this list of POJO.

```
public class SimpleBean {
     public List<Object> constructObject() {
       List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
       // construct objects
       return objects;
     }
}
```

Then in my camel route i want to generate json from my bean method. Here what i did and don't seem to work

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("quartz expression")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "work started")
            .bean(simpleBean, "constructObjects")
            .marshal()
            .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .to("file:C:/data/export/JSON")
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("test.json"))
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "work completed");
}
```

camel return a file with a UUID with no extension and with NULL as content. What am i missing here guys !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the filename you have to set the header **before** the call to file:

```
        .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("test.json"))
        .to("file:C:/data/export/JSON")
```

Your method is named constructObject and not constructObject**s** but I think that is a typo because otherwise you get an error.

The NULL I can't simulate. With following route:

```
public static class SimpleBean {
    public List<Object> constructObject() {
           List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
           objects.add("entry");
           return objects;
         }
}

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {

        public void configure() {
            from("direct:start")
            .bean(SimpleBean.class, "constructObject")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("test.json"))
            .to("file:C:/tmp/JSON");
        }
    };
}
```

I get an output file named test.json and with content:

```
["entry"]
```